# With QPrinter::HighResolution not printing

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprinter, qwebenginepage

I implement the ability to print reports in my project. Reports are presented as HTML content. I use for print QWebEnginePage. I need high resolution print output for reports:

```
QPrinter printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
```

But when printing with the "print" function, print fails, with message in debug:

> QImage: out of memory, returning null image

When printing with ScreenResolution, everything is fine, but the result is poor quality.
Version Qt - 5.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are indeed running out of memory.
Try to convert your web page into something that renders better, e.g. PDF and print the PDF instead.

Comment: It is possible to print the PDF, with Qt libraries?

Comment: I thought there was but I was wrong, PDFium is interesting, but this means loading PDF into a QImage again - which is not what we want here.

Comment: There is no such problem on version 5.8